# How to repeat to play a system sound and make a vibration using `AudioServicesPlayAlertSoundWithCompletion`?

Tags: swiftui, swift5

I'm currently developing an application using SwiftUI.

I want to know how to repeat playing a system sound and make a vibration using `AudioServicesPlayAlertSoundWithCompletion`.

I want to repeat them a couple of times and until when a user taps some button.

How could I do this?

---

ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import AudioToolbox

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var SoundID:SystemSoundID = 1151
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Sound")
                .padding()
                .onTapGesture {
                    makeSoundAndVibration()
                }
            Text("Stop")
                .padding()
                .onTapGesture {
                    stopSoundAndVibration()
                }
        }
    }
    func makeSoundAndVibration(){
        AudioServicesPlayAlertSoundWithCompletion(SoundID, nil)
        AudioServicesPlayAlertSoundWithCompletion(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)) {}
    }
    
    func stopSoundAndVibration(){
        // do someting to stop the sound and vibration
    }
}
```

SystemSoundTestApp.swift

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SystemSoundTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

---

Xcode: Version 12.0.1

iOS: 14.0